# Getting the child list of a node then iterate for similar values in another node in firebase and then get ita value(Firebase android))

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

My Firebase data stracture:

```
Bids-
    -jobID
          -userID : 1
          -userID2 : 1
Jobs
   -jobID
      -name:''
      -location:''
      -desc:''

Users
    -userID
         -name:'name1'
         -image: 'downloadUrl'
    -UserID2
          -name:'name2'
          -image: 'downloadUrl'
```

I am able to geta all the keys under jobID in Bids i.e userID and userID2 using this code:

```
mBidders.child(getIntent().getExtras().getString("jobID")).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            List<String> lt = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (DataSnapshot mSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                lt.add(String.valueOf(mSnapshot.getKey()));

            }

            for (String userId : lt) {

                Log.d("users", userId);

                getUsersInfo(userId);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Now when i want to get all the values under each user in the User using this method:

```
 getUsersInfo(String userId){

    Query query = mUsers.child(userId);

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, BiddedJobViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, BiddedJobViewHolder>(

            Users.class,
            R.layout.bidder_profile_row,
            BiddedJobViewHolder.class,
            query

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BiddedJobViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getUser());
            viewHolder.setImge(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());

        }
    };

    bidRecycleView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


}
```

It worked at first but only retrieving one users information to the recycleview on adding another user its replaced with the new one(in the recycleview). Now when i run the app, i get this error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.toni.patakazi.model.Users
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zze(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
       at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:154)
       at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:143)
       at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:183)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6067)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6100)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5282)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5158)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2061)
       at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:562)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1408)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:580)
       at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3379)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3188)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3632)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15927)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5113)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1959)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1813)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1722)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15927)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5113)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:633)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:568)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15927)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5113)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1959)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1813)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1722)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15927)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5113)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:633)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:568)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15927)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5113)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1959)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1813)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1722)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15927)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5113)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:633)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:568)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15927)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5113)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2445)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2142)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1267)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6501)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:800)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
    at android.v
```

I don't seem to understand the error.If there is another better way of doing i'll really appreciate it

Comment: where did you define bidRecycleView ?

Comment: at onCreateView         bidRecycleView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.biddersRV);
     
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm = new GridLayoutManager(BiddedJobActivity.this,3);

        bidRecycleView.setLayoutManager(lm);
        bidRecycleView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(3, dpToPx(3), true));
        bidRecycleView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

Comment: and also xml code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above is a format error you result is of type Users while you are capturing it as a String 
Try :

```
  //Get Jobs 
   Map<String, String> mapJobs = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for( DataSnapshot i : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String jobs = i.getValue(String.class);
        mapJobs.put(i.getKey(),jobs);
    }
    ArrayList<String> jobsList = new ArrayList<>(mapJobs.values());


   //Get Bids 
   Map<String, String> mapBids = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for( DataSnapshot i : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String bid = i.getValue(String.class);
        mapBids.put(i.getKey(),bid);


    }
    ArrayList<String> bidList = new ArrayList<>(mapBids.values());
```

Comment: after getting the bidlist, how do i iterate it to get all the values from the users node above?

Comment: for loop through the list